# Java: Instance double arrays element values modification issue

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables

I am new to Java. I have a class for which instances can be created. Within the class I define two instance variables:

`double[] array1;`

`double[] array2;`

The arrays will be of equal length.

Within the class I then have a method1 that first populates `array1` and then another method2 in which I want to set some of the `array2` values = the values in array1 (based on array element index) but also then modify (perform additional operation on) some of the values in array2 (based on array element index). I have tried to do this within method2 by first setting:

`array2 = array1;`

and then modifying some of the array2 values based on element index but I see that array1 has been completely modified to equal array2 so realise there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach in Java.

Comment: if you want to modify elements in an array you need to do it like `array2[index] = array1[index]`

Comment: I realise that. I do that within a `for` loop but I thought I could set all the elements in array2 equal to elements in array1 first before I modify some of the elements in array2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using assignment with array1 to set array2, you should probably use Arrays.copyOf():

```
array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);
```

Hopefully that'll help

Comment: I went with this method thanks. Also I already had the required `import java.util.Arrays;` in my class file.

Comment: Note that `clone()` is more efficient than `Arrays.copyOf` if you want to create a copy of the whole array.

Comment: efficient w.r.t. memory or processing speed?

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in Java are objects, and variables hold only references. Thus `array1 = array2` only assigns `array2`'s reference to the variable `array1`, and does not copy the contents.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning `array2 = array1` sets `array2` to point to the array as `array1`. Whenever you modify the array (e.g., `array[0] = 123`) both variables will "see" the change, since they both point to the same array. If you want to copy the elements of the array, you'll have to do so by iterating over the array and assigning values to it (or use a helper method that does just that, such as `Arrays.copyOf`). E.g.:

```java
// Assumption: Both arrays are initialized and array1.length = array2.length

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    array2[i] = array1[i];
    // some additional logic on array2[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `array2=array1`, you are adding a reference of `array2` to `array1`. So whenever you make changes to `array2`, by virtue of reference, `array1` will also change. You need to therefore copy values from one array to other and not pass reference from one array to other.

If you want an one-liner answer

```
System.arrayCopy(arrayA, 0, arrayB, 0, arrayB.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

`array2 = array1;` points `array2` reference to the same instance which is being referred by `array1` which means that if you change a value using any one of these references, the value accessed using the other one will be same.

Do it as

```
array2 = array1.clone();
```

It will assign a copy of the instance referred by `array1` to `array2`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] y = x.clone();
        x[2] = 5;
        System.out.println(x[2]);
        System.out.println(y[2]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
3
```